# how can I check with css if the selector :out-of-range is less than or greater than the input range?

Tags: css

I have a input where I want to add 3 conditions:

1. if valure is greater than 10, the background color will be green
2. if the value is between 4 and 10, the background color will be yellow
3. if the value is less than 4, the background color will be red

I would like to do it only with css and the only way I thought is with the example below where I just need to check if the value is above or below the range. Can anyone tell me if it is possible?

```css
.number-check {
  color: white;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.number-check:out-of-range {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<input class="number-check" type="number" min="5" max="10">
```

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge is this not possible with css. However try using javascript instead.

```js
const numCheck = document.getElementById("number-check");

numCheck.addEventListener('keyup',function(){
    if (this.value > 4 && this.value < 10) {
      // make yellow
      numCheck.style.background = "yellow";
    } else {
      // make green
      numCheck.style.background = "green";
    }
});
```

```html
<input id="number-check" type="number" min="5" max="10">
```